# Looking for a Fae book that includes the Cú Sidhe

Tags: story-identification, books, fairy

What I can remember from the book is it was in a modern setting with a portal that took the main character into the fae world through a graffiti mural?

The cú sídhe were involved towards the end in a battle.

I think the cover was black with a set of wings in the centre but it’s definitely not Tithe by Holly Black, just similar.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[A Crack in Everything](https://sjohart.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/book-review-saturday-a-crack-in-everything/)* by Ruth Frances Long

[image: Front cover of A Crack in Everything]

> The story introduces us to Izzy (Isabel) Gregory, who lives with her parents in a Dublin suburb. She has friends, she is into music, she has a part-time job in a coffee shop and she loves ‘town’ – as most people who live in the Dublin area refer to the city centre. One afternoon as she strolls through the streets, she is captivated by a beautiful piece of graffiti, an angel painted on a wall (which did actually exist in reality; I often saw it myself!), but as she is sucked into the power of the image, she finds herself being assaulted. She had noticed herself being followed by someone whom she took to be a homeless man, and it is he who shoves her against the wall and steals her phone – but then, before Izzy’s eyes, he vanishes into thin air. As Izzy struggles to get her phone back, she finds herself drawn into a different world, one which exists side-by-side with the human one, but peopled with entirely different Dubliners. The ‘homeless man’ is no such thing – he is a member of the Sídhe (pronounced ‘Shee’), the fairy-folk of Irish lore and legend, and another member of the Sídhe, Jinx, comes to Izzy’s aid. Thus begins a fast-paced, emotional story which takes in the Sídhe, angels and demons, magic and myth and the fate of the universe itself – all of which hangs on Izzy’s being brave enough to face up to her true identity, her role as more than a mere teenage girl, and her ability to deal with her complicated feelings for Jinx who – as a newly-acquired voice in her head keeps telling her – cannot be trusted.

Found with a search for `novel faerie portal "graffiti"`. Putting the quotes around 'graffiti' seemed necessary to force that to show up in the results.

Comment: Yes this is what I was thinking of thank you so much!